# Best method of transferring information between Gstreamer objects

Tags: gstreamer, congestion-control

In a gstreamer pipeline, I need a downstream element (a congestion control module) change the properties of an upstream element (an encoder) on the fly. What is the best mechanism to transfer this information?

Answer (score 0):

I would the element reporting post a message on the bus (see `fpsdisplaysink` for example). The application polling the bus can then react to that message and set something on some element as desired. That way the logic how to react is at the application layer and not necessarily on the elements themselves.

Alternatively check the GStreamer QOS handling which is already in place. Usually video sinks report if they received a video frame to late and report this upstream. Usually this continues to the file source where then the element decides to drop some frames to catch up again. So your encoder may intercept a similar perhaps custom message from your congestion control element and act accordingly.